# package dependencies

Tags: dependencies

While installing ubuntu from ubuntu software center, i got the following error:

```
package dependencies could not be resolved
```

After clicking detail button, shows the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgl1 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libtar0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Comment: what do you want to install? ubuntu??

Comment: There's no such package 'ubuntu' in ubuntu repositories. Also, which version of ubuntu are you in?

Comment: I think VIPIN is trying to install vlc, but need their confirmation.

Comment: sorry by mistake i type ubuntu insted of vlc.

Comment: actually i am trying to install vlc